# jQuery: Sliding image from right to left and vice versa

Tags: jquery

I have an image gallery that opens a slideshow on image click and fades in and out the next image, but I'd like to create a slide effect from right to left and vice versa. How can I do it without plugins?
Thank you all.

```
<section id="gallery">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="image-gallery">           
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 image">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <a href="F50.jpg"><img src="F50.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    <div class="img-overlay">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>       
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 image">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <a href="SpyderGT.png"><img src="SpyderGT.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    <div class="img-overlay">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div><!-- End image gallery -->
    </div><!-- End container --> 
</section>
```

```
$nextButton.click(function(event) {
$("#overlay img").hide();
var $currentImgSrc = $("#overlay img").attr("src");
var $currentImg = $('#image-gallery img[src="' + $currentImgSrc + '"]');
var $nextImg = $($currentImg.closest(".image").next().find("img"));
var $images = $("#image-gallery img");
if ($nextImg.length > 0) { 
    $("#overlay img").attr("src", $nextImg.attr("src")).fadeIn(800);            
} else {
    $("#overlay img").attr("src", $($images[0]).attr("src")).fadeIn(800);            
}
event.stopPropagation();
});

$prevButton.click(function(event) {
$("#overlay img").hide();
var $currentImgSrc = $("#overlay img").attr("src");
var $currentImg = $('#image-gallery img[src="' + $currentImgSrc + '"]');
var $nextImg = $($currentImg.closest(".image").prev().find("img"));
$("#overlay img").attr("src", $nextImg.attr("src")).fadeIn(800);
event.stopPropagation();
});
```